# Is a single AWS Cognito Region, us-west-2 for example, suitable for serving Canada, US and Puerto Rico?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm looking at my options for a managed sign-on service and AWS Cognito looks promising.

I notice that it's user pools etc do not currently replicate across regions. I wanted to confirm that 1 region is sufficient `us-west-#` for example (or `us-east-#`) would be sufficient for an application that has users spread across Canada, the US and Puerto Rico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, not only in the case of Cognito,  the closer your users are in the data center that hosts your services the better.  And this is only so you can minimize the propagation delays between your clients and the data center hosting your service.

Therefore, if you have to choose one region, choose the one that the majority of your clients are closer to.

AWS Cognito, does not replicate userPools across regions at the moment. Therefore, if you want to use the AccessToken against that userPool you need to go to the region that the userPool resides.

Now, every other service that accepts accessTokens, will accept your token  inside AWS, outside AWS in any region.

Comment: yes, that makes sense, but users can move. Airplanes, cars, trains etc. So while they may be close to one resource today that might not be the case tomorrow. Behind the scenes we could use some application logic to pin that user to a Cognito Region which could work. Do access token provided by Cognito work across regions? If it's IAM based, which is global, my assumption is yes, they work cross region, but I have not seen specific confirmation of that.

Comment: I amended my reply  to address your comment

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this supplementary detail to the question as a reference for the token types that Cognito returns. As I just found it by googling some of the info in the answer above.

Using the *AccessToken* against the userPool would be done for things like updating the user's account information. Which would be required to use the region the pool resides in since pools are not replicated.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

**ID Token**

> The ID token is represented as a JSON Web Key Token (JWT). The token contains claims about the identity of the authenticated user. For example, it includes claims such as *name, family_name, phone_number, etc.* For more information about standard claims, see the OpenID Connect specification. A client app can use this identity information inside the application. The ID token can also be used to authenticate users against your resource servers or server applications. When an ID token is used outside of the application against your web APIs, you must verify the signature of the ID token before you can trust any claims inside the ID token.
>
> The ID token expires one hour after the user authenticates. You should not process the ID token in your client or web API after it has expired.

**Access Token**

> The access token is also represented as a JSON Web Key Token (JWT). It contains claims about the authenticated user, but unlike the ID token, it does not include all of the user's identity information. The primary purpose of the access token is to authorize operations in the context of the user in the user pool. For example, you can use the access token against Amazon Cognito Identity to update or delete user attributes. The access token can also be used with any of your web APIs to make access control decisions and authorize operations in the context of the user. As with the ID token, you must first verify the signature of the access token in your web APIs before you can trust any claims inside the access token.
>
> The access token expires one hour after the user authenticates. It should not be processed after it has expired.

**Refresh Token**

> The refresh token can only be used against Amazon Cognito to retrieve a new access or ID token.
>
> By default, the refresh token expires 30 days after the user authenticates. When you create an app for your user pool, you can set the app's Refresh token expiration (days) to any value between 1 and 3650.

Comment: I want to add, I spoke with an AWS Solutions Architect and they confirmed that 1 region is sufficient for US, Canada and Puerto Rico. Additionally, depending on your latency requirements, it may be appropriate globally. You would need to be sure the latency is acceptable for your use case before you do so. For example us-west to Germany could be 100-200ms. If that's fine, you are good to go. That applies to Cognito Sync and Login.